# Help with solving DE: $x^2y'' + 2xy' - 2y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone give me an advice that helps me to solve this kind of DE:
$$
x^2 \cdot y'' + 2x \cdot y’ - 2y = 0
$$
knowing that $$ y_1=Ax+{B \over x^2} $$ is a solution.

I've tried to solve it by reduction of order (described [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx)) by assuming that $$y_2=y_1 \cdot v$$ is a solution where $v(x)$ is a function.

I've calculated $y_2''$ and $y_2'$ then I've tried using them in the original DE and I got:
$$v''(Ax^3+B)+v'(4Ax^2-{2B \over x})=0$$
Next I assumed that there exists a function $w$ such that $w=v'$ and $w'=v''$

so the equation above reduced to the first order DE:
$$
w'(Ax^3+B)+w(4Ax^2-{2B \over x})=0
$$

My intuition tells me that I should guess a function $u(x)$ such that the DE above writes like $$w' \cdot u+w \cdot u'=0 \iff(w\cdot u)'=0\implies w\cdot u=C$$ 
where $u(x)$ could be something like: $$u={4 \over 3}\cdot Ax^3-2B \cdot ln(x) $$
but it doesn't work because: $$u\neq (Ax^3+B)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation). 
Particular solutions have the form $y=x^\lambda$ (substitute this into the equation and obtain a quadratic equation for $\lambda$). Thus, in your case, the general solution is $y=C_1x+C_2x^{-2}$. (This can be guessed immediately from the form of $y_1$, without writing out and solving the quadratic.)

Comment: You mean that it can be solved only numerically? If that's true then what part of the DE tells you that? I'm asking you because I want to learn to tell when smth. can't be done algebraically. Thx.

Comment: Why numerically? This is a completely algebraic procedure. Substitute $x^\lambda$ into your equation; you get $\lambda(\lambda-1)+2\lambda-2=0$, or $\lambda^2+\lambda-2=0$. The roots are $1$ and $-2$.

Comment: I've wrote the comment initially when you've written that it's a Euler equation and I thought it should be solved by numerical means. But now I see, it's Cauchy-Euler which can be solve algebraically. Your help answered my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For $x = e^z$, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}.\frac{dz}{dx}=e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz}$$

Now $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{dy}{dx}).e^{-z}=e^{-z}\frac{d}{dz}(e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz})=e^{-z}(e^{-z}\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz})=e^{-2z}(\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{dy}{dz})$$

Substituting this in your original equation, we will get :

$$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{dy}{dz}+2\frac{dy}{dz}-2y=0$$, where $y$ is a function of $z$.

This equation can now be easily solved.

Comment: This is a good solution too but the derivation process is error-prone. Although it works :)

Comment: @EugenMihailescu error prone how??

Comment: It's easy to lose the track while doing all these derivation steps. Of course, that's subjective because it depends from one person to other (ex: an engineer vs. a high-school student).