# What is the particular equation of the solution of $ x^2 \ddot y + 2x \dot y - 6y = x^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the particular equation of the solution of $ x^2 \ddot y + 2x \dot y - 6y = 0$?

I found the complementary equation to be $ y_c=  C_1 x^{-3} + C_2 x^2 $. But what method should I use to find the particular equation of this differential equation with variable coefficients?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/828924/876009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2 \ddot y + 2x \dot y - 6y = x^2$$
Substitute $x=e^t$:
$$\ddot y +\dot y - 6y = e^{2t}$$
The particular solution should be on the form:
$$\implies y_p(t)=Ate^{2t}$$
$$y_p(x)=Ax^2\ln x$$

Comment: Following this, I got $y_p (x) = (x^2 lnx)/5 $ But if the correct answer is $y_p (x) = (x^2 lnx)/5 - x^2/25 $, how this $x^2 / 25$ was computed?

Comment: Well $x^2\ln x/5$ is correct for the particular solution  @JordanG  $x^2/25$ is absorbed  by the homogeneous solution  $cx^2$